# Strategy for picking the largest column in a dynamic view?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this stair case effect because the browser will insert an extra div below the last div if it will fit.

[image]

I need it to pick the longest div and use that as guideline as where to start the next row.

Trick is, the amount of columns can be anywhere from 1 to really big, depending upon how wide the screen is.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you please post some code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

> I need it to pick the longest div and use that as guideline as where
>   to start the next row.

You can loop through all the divs in the document and find the longest div as follows:

```js
height = "0px";
var all_div = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var x = 0; x < all_div.length; ++x) {
  if (getComputedStyle(all_div[x]).height > height)
    height = getComputedStyle(all_div[x], null).height;
}
console.log("the div width longest height is", height);
```

```css
div {
  border: solid green;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
}

.d:nth-child(1) {
  height: 100px;
}

.d:nth-child(2) {
  height: 500px;
}

.d:nth-child(3) {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.d:nth-child(4) {
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="d">100px</div>
<div class="d">500px</div>
<div class="d">50px</div>
<div class="d">70px</div>
```

Comment: But the divs are being added dynamically by javascript from JSON data.

Comment: So you want the code to keep checking for the longest div every 5 sec?

Comment: naw they are added from a set of JSON using underscore templates ... like instantaneously ... < 10ms I have no idea how to do this.